# My ubuntu box is not opening in graphical mode

Tags: 12.04, boot, graphics, virtualization

I copied a big data in `/temp` of my RHEl VM. Now my system stopped booting in graphical mode.

Can anyone tell me, How can i delete `/tmp` of my VM without affecting my VM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to just delete the content of the /temp folder of your VM but without the need to boot the VM OS, all you need is a Linux LiveCD (your choice here, I would recommend a small one to get it fast from the Internet if you don't have one at hand).

Use the LiveCD iso as the boot device in your VM, boot the VM with the LiveCD iso, accesss your partition with the /temp folder and delete what you wish. Finally, reboot and you're done (don't forget to change the VM settings to remove the LiveCD iso as boot device so you boot the VM OS when you reboot).

Good luck and let us know what happens!

Comment: Just download any Ubuntu version, he/she never said how good bandwidth he/she has, I'm running off a 100mbit/10mbit line, that's  pretty standard here...